# How to have single store for each tab in redux [reactjs]?

Tags: reactjs, redux

We have a web app composed of several pages containing links of data retrieved from database. Upon clicking one link[data], the user should be directed to another page.  For navigation between pages, we have used breadcrumb. The breadcrumb is stored in redux store. Currently, when the user tries to ctrl+click or open link in new tab, we managed to use single store across multiple tabs. Hence, if the user opens 3 separate links [data] in new tabs, the updates made on the breadcrumb affect previously opened tabs when these tabs/pages are refreshed. For example:

In homepage, I have these links:

Data_1
Data_2
Data_3

Current breadcrumb in the homepage is like this:
HomePage/

Once the user opens Data_1 in new tab, the expected breadcrumb in the new tab is:
HomePage/Data_1/

Similarly, if the user tries to open Data_2 and Data_3, in new tabs, the breadcrumbs should appear as follows for tab 1 and tab 2, respectively:

HomePage/Data_2/

HomePage/Data_3/

In the current implementation, I managed to update the state of breadcrumb whenever new links are opened such that breadcrumb[0] would be equivalent to HomePage while breadcrumb[1] was initially Data_1, then became Data_2, and lastly Data_3. Hence, the last value of breadcrumb[1] is Data_3 since that's the last opened link. My problem is that whenever the user refreshes previously opened tabs/pages corresponding to Data_1 and Data_2, since they are all using a single store and breadcrumb[1] has been changed to Data_3, the breadcrumbs in Data_1 and Data_2 pages also become Data_3.

In this case, I can just think of using multiple stores since I perceive that it could be the only solution given my use case. Meanwhile, I can't find any sufficient documentation online regarding using multiple stores in redux. Maybe I can pass the store to the next page in params...? something like that

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To emulate per-tab same site persistency, I would, right before the page is about to be refreshed (window.beforeunload or similar)

1 - Write to localStorage about my breadcrumb

2 - Refresh

3 - Read from localStorage about my breadcrumb to initialize myself properly (so the data here SHOULD be mine because i just wrote it)

4 - remove breadcrumb information from localStorage (to prevent other tabs from reading it)

Now, you still have the case where the user just closes the tab, so you would have stale data about the breadcrumb in your localStorage. You can add a little expiration mechanism (you might consider that data in the localStorage older than 10 seconds is stale and just pretend it isn't here  and delete it at step 3.) Cookies would work pretty much the same, with a built-in expiration mechanism.